# how to save emoji in oracle database using php and retrieve them again and display them on php page

Tags: php, oracle, emoji

I am setting up a simple chat room and I want to be using emoji too how do I save them in oracle and display them on my page.

```
$conn = oci_connect("username", "password", "10.*.*.*","AL32UTF8");
```

This is for the connection set to AL32UTF8 as charset

```
insert into chat_message values(chat_id,message,sender,receiver,sent_date,delivery_date);

select message,sent_date from chat_message where receiver="$_SESSION";
```

AM expecting to see the emoji on my webpage as it was saved in the database. but for now, am only seeing question marks being stored in the database and as output.

Comment: What is the character set on your database? Check with `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');`

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252      and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit kinldy help me out. thank you.

Comment: Character set `WE8MSWIN1252` does not support any Emoji. Either migrate your database to UTF-8 `AL32UTF8` or use data type `NVARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR2` for your column.

Comment: how to migrate database to   UTF-8 AL32UTF8 ? thank you

Comment: See [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) and/or [Database Migration Assistant for Unicode Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm)

Comment: thank you. but is this the safest way seeing that i have data already in my database? have adopted the option of using datatype  NVARCHAR2 but sill it is not working. advise me Sir.

Comment: No, you don't have the data in your database. If you run `DUMP(message, 1016)` then you will see you have actually the question mark (or `¿`) in your database. The emoji is lost and it is not possible to get it back.